# How to write a regex for string matches which starts with any alphabets AND ends with numbers and can have N num of characters in between in js

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regex for string matches which starts with any alphabets AND ends with numbers and can have N num of characters in between in js

It should accept

```
Abc%4
abc&^z4a2
a1 etc
```

I tried `/(^[^a-z][0-9]$)/` but it isnt working

Comment: Did you try regex101.com, which explains regular expressions?

Comment: What does "N num of characters in between" mean? Some fixed N? Any N?

Comment: `/^[a-z].*[0-9]$/im`

Comment: Oops ,  I actually tried/(^[a-z][0-9]$)/ sorry for the mistake in the question

Comment: @AvinashRaj - That probably should be `.*?` in the middle. Also, the `m` flag may not be desired.

Comment: @Ted op clearly mention that he wants the line to be end with a number. So greedy `.*` match is the perfect one for this case instead of non-greedy `.*?` . And also I love to use `m` modifier whenever `^$` operators used in the regex because without `m`, no match would occur if the input string contain `\n` or `\r` characters.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Good point about the greedy match, since backtracking would only have to be for one character. Note, though, that OP might not want to match a string containing line break characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/^[a-zA-Z]\S+\d$/` - if white space is not allowed

`/^[a-zA-Z].*\d$/` - if white space is allowed

**Note:** I'm not capturing any matches as this is not in the requirement

Hope this helps!

Comment: But you are accepting strings that start with a digit, which is contrary to the requirements.

Comment: The range `[A-z]` isn't right. It includes a number of non-alphabetic characters. You need to use either `[A-Za-z]` or use the `i` flag on the regex.

Comment: Okay, now it looks right. You don't need the `+` after the character class, and the `gm` flags are questionable (but probably harmless for OP's application).

Answer (score 0):

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SJgOs6/3)**

try likr this : `([a-zA-Z])(.*)(\d+)`

```js
var str =" Abc%4,abc&^z4a2,a1 etc";
console.log(str.match(/([a-zA-Z])(.*)(\d+)/g))
```

Comment: That will accept a string that starts with a digit, not what OP wants.

Comment: Yeah, that's still not right. You don't have anchors, so it will match on only a substring. Even your example shows it matching a string that starts with white space (not with an alphabetic character, as OP requires). The `\b` at the end is useless; OP wants the entire string to end with a digit.

Comment: @TedHopp is not  matching a string that starts with white space

Comment: Really? Read the question again. OP wants to test whether `str` starts with a letter and ends with a digit. You wrote a regex to find a substring with that property, not what OP wants.